# Any connection between extension of algebraic structure and forcing of set theory?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, forcing, extension, field-extensions

Any connection between extension of algebraic structure and forcing of set theory? And more, are there any approach from one of the two to other field to solve problem?

Comment: Maybe of your interest: [https://www.proquest.com/docview/305437237](https://www.proquest.com/docview/305437237)

Comment: @MohammadGolshani, thank you for the link.